# How to zip multiple folders generating multiple .zip files in gulp?

Tags: gulp

My folder structure looks like this:

```
- /projects
- /projects/proj1
- /projects/proj2
- /projects/proj3
- /zips
```

For each folder in `projects` (proj1, proj2 and proj3) I want to zip contents of each of those folders and generate `proj1.zip`, `proj2.zip` and `proj3.zip` in `/zips` folder.

Following example function generates single zip file from `proj1` folder

```
zip = require('gulp-zip');
gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('./projects/proj1/*')
        .pipe(zip('proj1.zip'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./zips'));
});
```

But how I can execute such task for each folder in projects? I can get all folders to zip by `gulp.src('./projects/*')` but what then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old question I know and I am pretty new to gulp so this might be considered a hack but I have just been trying to do what you are after and I ended up with this.

My file structure is this:

```
proj
proj/dist
proj/dist/sub01
proj/dist/sub02
proj/dist/sub03
proj/zipped
```

And my task ended up like this:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var foreach = require("gulp-foreach");
var zip = require("gulp-zip");

gulp.task("zip-dist", function(){
   return gulp.src("./dist/*")
       .pipe(foreach(function(stream, file){
          var fileName = file.path.substr(file.path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
          gulp.src("./dist/"+fileName+"/**/*")
              .pipe(zip(fileName+".zip"))
              .pipe(gulp.dest("./zipped"));

          return stream;
       }));
});
```

It grabs all the first level contents of `./dist` as its source and then pipes it to [`gulp-foreach`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-foreach).

`gulp-foreach` looks at each item and I use a plain javascript `substr()` to get the name of the current item which I store as a variable.

Finally I set a new `src` using the stored fileName var and pipe the result to [`gulp-zip`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-zip) using the stored var again as the name of the zipped file.

The result is a structure that looks like this:

```
proj
proj/dist
proj/dist/sub01
proj/dist/sub02
proj/dist/sub03
proj/zipped
proj/zipped/sub01.zip
proj/zipped/sub02.zip
proj/zipped/sub03.zip
```

Again, I am a million miles from being an expert but this worked for me and if I understand the question might work for you as well or at least give you some ideas.

Comment: Is this considered to be the only solution? I know this is 2 years old, have you found a cleaner way to do this in the past 2 years of experience?

Thank you for your answer though... Very helpful!! :)

Comment: After using Gulp for a little while I came to the conclusion that I was better off ditching it completely and writing my own Node scripts to do this kind of thing. I found this to be faster then Gulp, more powerful and much more intuitive to create. Also, better community and documentation. Only my opinion though so no kind of real answer I'm afraid.