# How to gulp zip multiple folders and exclude some files?

Tags: gulp, zip

I am a beginner at using Gulp and I don't know a lot about what is possible and what not. I would like to achieve the following:

my setup for 1 project:

.dist 
├── client-1 
│   ├── campaign-1 
│   │   ├── project-a 
│   │   │   ├── css (folder) 
│   │   │   ├── js (folder) 
│   │   │   ├── images (folder) 
│   │   │   ├── index.html 
│   │   │   └── preview.html

(Every project has the same structure. I have multiple clients with different names with different campaigns.)

!! I would like to make a zip file for each project with all files and folders included, except the file *preview.html*. If the name can be the name of the project, that would be even better.

.dist 
├── client-1 
│   ├── campaign-1 
│   │   ├── project-a 
│   │   │   ├── **css (folder)** 
│   │   │   ├── **js (folder)** 
│   │   │   ├── **images (folder)** 
│   │   │   ├── **index.html** 
│   │   │   ├── *preview.html* 

│   │   │   └── **project-a.zip** (new)

If I unzip the zipfile, I would like to see the following (not inside a folder):

- css (folder and contents)
- js (folder and contents)
- images (folder and contents)
- index.html

How can I set up Gulp task(s) to do this zipping for me?

Comment: [`gulp-zip`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-zip) + [excluding files/directories from Gulp task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384239/excluding-files-directories-from-gulp-task) = it's possible

Comment: Hello @SvenSchoenung, Also specific folders with wildcard folders in between?

Comment: Were you wondering how to do this, or really just wondering if your goal is impossible?

Comment: I was wondering if AND how this goal was achievable. @henry

Comment: Okay, I thought so. As @SvenSchoenung said, you'll need `gulp-zip` for the zipping, and (as in the answer to that linked question) you'll use a `!negation` glob to exclude the `preview.html`s. To do each project separately use [`gulp-flatMap`](https://github.com/mariusGundersen/gulp-flatMap). To name the zip after the project, you'll do something like in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256964) (there `gulp-flatMap` is called by its old name, `gulp-foreach`).

Comment: @ henry Thank you! I'll have a look for sure!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the help of **[gulp-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-zip)**.

If you want to exclude specific files or folders from zipping, you can amke use of regular expressions.
Check this once, [Excluding files/directories from Gulp task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384239/excluding-files-directories-from-gulp-task?noredirect=1&lq=1)

See below:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const zip = require('gulp-zip');

gulp.task('default', () => {
  return gulp.src([ 'js/**/*.js', '!js/**/*.min.js' ]) // Here I'm excluding .min.js files
    .pipe(zip('archive.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

If you want exclude or include any specific folders or files, you can do that with regex also . Let's say, If you want to exclude  folders which starts with underscore('_') symbol from **zip**, you do like this,

```
gulp.src('js/[^_]*/*.js'); // Here I'm excluding folders that start with '_' symbol
```

Just like, what we write in **javascript**, same regex will works here.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you, it is part of a solution, but i still want to target specific files at a specific "depth" of the filestructure.

Comment: Do you want to zip all projects at one shot or perform it one project at time?

Comment: Cinnakotla It would be nice to create a zip of every project in one campaign at a time... :-). Because If it would zip all projects an I would add more projects every time, it would only add up to time.